# How to get rid of the lockscreen?

Tags: boot, lock-screen

I tried to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.1; but, the system didn’t complete its upgrade.

I couldn’t pass through the lock screen and I can’t find the password box in the lockscreen. The lockscreen has an ‘X’ point instead of a cursor point.

Comment: If it stopped during an upgrade, or something got corrupted than you're most likely going to have to do a fresh install of Ubuntu.

Comment: Really!Is there no other way(I am not a pro)I can revive my pc?My data will be lost?

Comment: Can you get into console mode. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to do so.
Also if you can share screenshot (maybe using your phone )that may be useful

Comment: Yes,I can access console now what I need to type to know what is real issue in my pc?